# Reset an Elm select dropdown value

Tags: elm

I basically have a little select dropdown like this:

```
viewDropdown : Model -> Html Msg
viewDropdown model =
    let
        options =
            [ ( "", "-- Select --" )
            , ( "not_available", "Unavailable" )
            , ( "available", "Available" )
            ]

        buildOption ( k, v ) =
            option [ value k, selected (k == model.isAvailable) ] [ text v ]

        viewOptions =
            options
                |> List.map
                    (\( k, v ) ->
                        buildOption ( k, v )
                    )
    in
    div [ class "styled-select" ]
        [ select
            [ on "change" (Decode.map (UpdateAvailability) targetValue)
            ]
            viewOptions
        ]
```

If the user selects "Available", a modal pops up and they are prompted to confirm. If they hit "Cancel", I want the Select dropdown's value to reset to the value of "". This is not the case and although my model reflects the a Nothing val, the dropdown selection option is still on "Available". Any idea on what I can do to reset the DOM state?

Answer (score 1):

While this doesn't answer why your code doesn't work, it seems that if you add the step of confirming the selection, then code will work:

Ellie example, with full code below: https://ellie-app.com/3P5TTM9YqVWa1

```
module Main exposing (main)

import Browser
import Html exposing (Html, button, div, text, option, select)
import Html.Events exposing (onClick, on, targetValue)
import Html.Attributes exposing (value, selected, class)
import Json.Decode as Decode
import Task

type alias Model =
    { isAvailable : String , showConfirm: Bool }

init : Model
init =
    { isAvailable = "-", showConfirm = False }

type Msg
    = UpdateAvailability String
    | ConfirmYes
    | Reset

update : Msg -> Model -> Model
update msg model =
    case msg of
        UpdateAvailability v ->
            { model | isAvailable = v, showConfirm = (v == "available") }

        ConfirmYes ->
            { model | showConfirm = False }

        Reset ->
            { model | isAvailable = "-", showConfirm = False }



viewDropdown : Model -> Html Msg
viewDropdown model =
    let
        options =
            [ ( "-", "-- Select --" )
            , ( "not_available", "Unavailable" )
            , ( "available", "Available" )
            ]

        buildOption ( k, v ) =
            option [ value k, selected (k == model.isAvailable) ] [ text v ]

        viewOptions = List.map buildOption options
    in
    div []
        [ select
            [ on "change" (Decode.map (UpdateAvailability) targetValue) ]
            viewOptions
        ]

viewConfirm model =
    if model.showConfirm then
        div []
            [ text "Really available?"
            , button [ onClick ConfirmYes ] [ text "Yes" ]
            , button [ onClick Reset ] [ text "No" ]
            ]
    else
        div [] []

view : Model -> Html Msg
view model =
    div []
        [ viewDropdown model
        , viewConfirm model
        , button [ onClick Reset ] [ text "Reset" ]
        ]


main : Program () Model Msg
main =
    Browser.sandbox
        { init = init
        , view = view
        , update = update
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you setting `model.isAvailable` to "" when hitting the close button? Your code should work as is https://ellie-app.com/3NYRvgwkHWPa1

Comment: Not quite. Here, I'm intercepting the update of "available" to decline a model state change and you'll see the error I'm facing. https://ellie-app.com/3NYRvgwkHWPa1

Answer (score 0):

Turns out, adding a `value` attribute to the `select` html will override the option `selected` state, so this is pretty important if you need your select input to be in sync with model state.

https://ellie-app.com/3NZgYQYKv2Fa1

Comment: That is invalid html, `select` can't use `value` attribute: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/select

Comment: @MarkusLaire Elm seems to interpret this just fine, and its the solution to my problem